# How to create in R a data frame based on certain conditions

Tags: r, dataframe, statistics, dataset

By using `datasets` package, I need to create a new data frame with only the cars with automatic transmision.

```
mtcars
                     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Valiant             18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
... more cars ...
Maserati Bora       15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8
Volvo 142E          21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2
```

I tried this.

```
local({pkg <- select.list(sort(.packages(all.available = TRUE)),graphics=TRUE)
  if(nchar(pkg)) library(pkg, character.only=TRUE)})
automatic = which(am==1)
automatic
# [1]  1  2  3 18 19 20 26 27 28 29 30 31 32
```

Then I tried to filter the mtcars dataframe with the automatic cars.

```
mtcars[automatic, am]
```

It is filtering indeed, it only shows cars with automatic transmision, but I guess there are other ways to do this.

I also need to create another data frame with vehicles with less than 16 milles per galon (mpg), and a vector with vehicles' weight more than 3000 libras.

Hope you guys can help me with this, I feel a bit lost. Thanks.

Comment: using dplyr, you could try: mtcars %>% filter(am == "1")

Comment: Is there any reason you do not want to use `subset`? e.g. `subset(mtcars, am == 1)` or `subset(mtcars, mpg < 16)` and so on? (I am not sure what the "datasets packet" is)

Comment: You are doing it right, but with more than one condition logical vectors (e.g. `automatic <- mtcars$am == 1`) are more flexible because you can then use the logical operators `&` or `|` `!` to combine them in various ways. If you use numeric indices you can't do that.

Comment: @mathematical.coffee OP must have meant "datasets package". (Do `find("mtcars")` to see that that's actually where `mtcars` lives.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create data frame with vehicles with less than 16 milles per galon (mpg), and a vector with vehicles' weight more than 3000 libras using this code:

```
> library(datasets)

> row_num <- mtcars$mpg < 16 & mtcars$wt > 3

> mtcars[row_num,]

                     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Duster 360          14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
Merc 450SLC         15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3
Cadillac Fleetwood  10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4
Lincoln Continental 10.4   8 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4
Chrysler Imperial   14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4
Dodge Challenger    15.5   8 318.0 150 2.76 3.520 16.87  0  0    3    2
AMC Javelin         15.2   8 304.0 150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0    3    2
Camaro Z28          13.3   8 350.0 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0    3    4
Ford Pantera L      15.8   8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4
Maserati Bora       15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8
```

Comment: This solution looks promising, I will have to wait a bit to try this at home. If it's working for me I will accept your answer :) thank you!